# Why is this <div> wider than its contents?

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, html

I have the following html code for a form (generated by rails):

[Form HTML](http://pastebin.com/D6CCu547)

Looking in Chrome's element inspector, the left `<div>` is behaving as expected, but the right `<div>` is encapsulating what's in the left `<div>` as well.

[image: Left <div>]
[image]

Why would it do this if the right `<div>` only contains what's in the right half of the form (not including the "Register" button)?

Here's the relevant CSS:

[Form CSS](http://pastebin.com/1BCgUmsy)

Comment: try using `display: inline-block` for this div

Comment: I`m sorry there is no class to edit on the CSS with the name right/left_half. Please make a jsfiddle to make it easier to help you.

Comment: @Ashish Chopra `display: inline-block` inside the `left_half` div only shifted the `right_half` div below the `left_half` one and it also made all the elements inside it inline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's because the `left_half` is set to `float: left`, so the `right_one`stacks on top of it.

You can... wrap them inside a `<div>` and set both half's to `float: left` for example.

Comment: But I already have them wrapped in a `<div>` with a class `edit_info`

Comment: Because everything inside that div that doesn't float as well can end above the floating elements.

Comment: You can try without, but I'm not sure about what will happen to the button, that i just noticed it's floating righ

Answer (score 0):

You are using

```css
.edit_info {
     width: 610px;
     margin: auto;
}
```

Use  `width: auto` instead:

```css
.edit_info {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: auto;
}
```